# Проблема с отрисовкой через шейдер на PowerVR (GLES 2.0)

Tags: gles2.0, android, шейдеры

Решил я тут недавно протестировать свое приложение на реальных устройствах, все было чудесно, пока я не столкнулся с Galaxy Nexus'ом и его PowerVR'ом - на нем не рисовалась мешь (mesh). Вот, собственно, код шейдеров (фрагментный и вершинный, соответственно):

```
#ifdef GL_ES
    #define LOWP lowp
    #define MEDIUMP mediump
    precision mediump float; 
#else
    #define LOWP
    #define MEDIUMP
#endif

uniform sampler2D u_texture;

varying MEDIUMP vec4 v_color;
varying MEDIUMP vec4 pos;
varying MEDIUMP vec2 v_texCoords;

void main() {
    gl_FragColor = v_color * texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoords);
} 



#ifdef GL_ES
    #define LOWP lowp
    #define MEDIUMP mediump
    precision mediump float; 
#else
    #define LOWP
    #define MEDIUMP
#endif

attribute MEDIUMP vec4 a_position;
attribute MEDIUMP vec2 a_texCoord0;
attribute MEDIUMP vec4 a_color;

uniform MEDIUMP mat4 u_projTrans;

varying MEDIUMP vec4 pos;
varying MEDIUMP vec2 v_texCoords;
varying MEDIUMP vec4 v_color;

void main() {
    v_color = a_color;
    v_texCoords = a_texCoord0;
    gl_Position =  u_projTrans * a_position;
    pos = gl_Position;
}
```

Да, возможно, проблема вовсе не в шейдере, а в том, как я его использую. Вообщем, ребят, очень прошу помочь с этой проблемой.